# parse string js function in JSON as a js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have PHP json string.

```
{"formatter":"function (){    return   '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '<\/b> sold <br><b>' + this.point.value + '<\/b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '<\/b>';   }"}
```

I can transform JSON into PHP STRING like this with help of this answer [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33506224/2542806)

```
{"formatter":function (){    return   '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '<\/b> sold <br><b>' + this.point.value + '<\/b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '<\/b>';   }}
```

But when i try to parse JSON into Object with

```
jQuery.parseJSON(variableContainingPHPJSONstring)
```

I have error like this.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 14

This is the JSON i am working on it is a HIGHCHART.

[I have this type of highchart config data coming from db=> php Array=> php json => js string => js object](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/)

I only have problem with function part here.
under **tooltip:formatter**

Comment: Functions are not allowed in JSON, so obviously parsing it fails.

Comment: The second one is not JSON anymore, but a javascript object. You can't parse that using `jQuery.parse`.

Comment: I know it... But i want a way to achive this...  @trincot

Comment: @t.niese It is actually just a string of php. I removed quotes.

Comment: If you know it is not JSON, why do you call your variable `json`?

Comment: @trincot I just used it is just an example. in real code varianble name is different.

Comment: The code you show in your jsfiddle is **not** JSON it is JavaScript code. You would serve the code to create the chart regularly as script and only request your data for the chart as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Functions aren't valid json.  You'll have to eval() the function if you want it usable. I would encourage you to find a way to avoid doing this, or have a tooltip function that accepts a row of data or whatever instead, but here's a working example of using eval() to do basically what you want.

```
var data = {
    key1: "123",
    key2: "junk",
    formatter: "(function(){return 4;})"
};

var formatter = eval(data.formatter);

console.log(formatter());
```